# Does a hybrid count as a fruit from the seven species?

Tags: blessing, fruits, bikkurim-first-fruits, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

If a hybrid of two different fruits from the seven species was grown, does it still count as a fruit from the seven species, or is it considered a fruit of its own, with regards to Bikkurim and the after blessing?

Comment: Can any of them actually interbreed with each other?

Comment: Not sure the practicality of the question. For Bikkurim one can only bring his best fruits, if it’s inferior quality then it can’t be brought. For the after blessing, if one eats a half kzayis each, from two different fruits of the seven species, even if they weren’t grafted, he would make the after blessing. So why should grafting be different? Ultimately, he ate a kzayis of fruit. There’s no requirement for it to be from one species

Comment: @DoubleAA it seems wheat and barley can become hybrid. https://www.google.com/search?q=can+wheat+and+barley+cross&client=safari&channel=iphone_bm&sxsrf=APwXEddkxJ-28Fs2RE_nejf4OqZwcC4e4Q%3A1683775838135&source=hp&ei=XmFcZIrsBcmh5NoPxY-Z0AQ&oq=can+wheat+and+barely&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBABGAAyBggAEBYQHjIICAAQCBAeEA0yCAgAEAgQHhANMggIABAIEB4QDTIICAAQigUQhgMyBwghEKABEAoyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoHCCMQigUQJzoICAAQigUQkQI6CwgAEIoFEMkDEJECOggIABCKBRCSAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CAguEIAEELEDOgUIABCABFCECVjGLWDqYWgBcAB4AYABjAGIAZYFkgEDMy4zmAEAoAEBsAEP&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp

Comment: @Chatzkel For wheat and barley the question is narrower since any dagan gets the special after blessing.